# IntersectionObserver: find out when element is outside viewport

Tags: javascript, intersection-observer

Using the [IntersectionObserver API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API), how can I find out when a particular element is outside of the viewport?

As soon as the user scrolls past the header, and the header is therefore no longer inside the viewport, I need to output a console log. I want to use the `IntersectionObserver` instead of a scroll event listener to minimalize load as it works asynchronously. The code I have so far is:

```
let options = {
   root: null, //root
   rootMargin: '0px',
   threshold: 1.0,
 };

 function onChange(changes, observer) {
    changes.forEach(change => {
       if (change.intersectionRatio < 0) {
          console.log('Header is outside viewport');
        }
    });
  }

  let observer = new IntersectionObserver(onChange, options);

  let target = document.querySelector('#header');
  observer.observe(target);
```

This code does not output any console logs. PS: my `<header>` element has an ID of `header`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems in your code:

- Your `options.threshold` is defined as "1". That means that `onChange` always executes when the `intersectionRatio` changes from a value <1 to 1 or vice versa. But what you actually want is a `threshold` of "0".
- The `intersectionRatio` is *never* below 0. Thus, you have to change your condition within the `if` clause to `change.intersectionRatio === 0`.